# Prove there are no positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^3 + y^3 = 10^3$.

Tags: proof-writing, fermat-numbers

I am familiar with Fermat's Last Theorem that there are no integers such that $x^3+y^3=z^3$, but I need a simpler proof that demonstrates that fact when we know that $x$ and $y$ are positive, and $z=10^3$.

Thank you!

Comment: And what a coincidence: GiantDuck also edited that question.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That's very strange, what possible motive would there be to edit a question, then ask a duplicate of said question?

Comment: @mrnovice I was hoping with a slightly different wording I would attract more answers.

Comment: It is a duplicate, but there are no complete answers there, whereas mrnovice quickly supplied a complete answer here. What is the moderation on such an event?

Comment: @Kaynex I believe mods can merge them...

Comment: @Kaynex What is essentially mrnovice's answer was given in the first two comments under the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Write the positive cube numbers up to $10$:

$1^3=1,\quad2^3=8,\quad 3^3=27,\quad4^3=64,\quad5^3=125,\quad6^3=216,\quad7^3=343,\quad8^3=512,\quad9^3=729,\quad10^3 =1000$

Now all you need to do is demonstrate that the sum of any two combinations of these does not equal $1000$.